# Ansible not able to find requirements.txt

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, pip, ansible

My directory structure is something like this

```
$ tree
├── Vagrantfile
├── files
│   ├── cmake
│   ├── pip-requirements.txt
│   └── profile
└── tasks
    └── main.yml
```

Contents of `main.yml`

```
---
- hosts: kurseve
  tasks:
      - name: Install pip
        pip:
          requirements: ../files/pip-requirements.txt
          virtualenv: /home/vagrant/venvs/cv
          virtualenv_python: python2.7
```

But when I try to provision the Vagrant box using the command `vagrant up --provision` from the project root. The error log shows that ansible was not able to find the `pip-requirements.txt` placed inside the `files/`

This is the error log

```
fatal: [kurseve]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/home/vagrant/venvs/cv/bin/pip2 install -r ../files/pip-requirements.txt",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null,
            "editable": true,
            "executable": null,
            "extra_args": null,
            "name": null,
            "requirements": "../files/pip-requirements.txt",
            "state": "present",
            "umask": null,
            "use_mirrors": true,
            "version": null,
            "virtualenv": "/home/vagrant/venvs/cv",
            "virtualenv_command": "virtualenv",
            "virtualenv_python": "python2.7",
            "virtualenv_site_packages": false
        },
        "module_name": "pip"
    },
    "msg": "\n:stderr: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../files/pip-requirements.txt'\n"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html) module expect `requirements` file to be on the target box:

> The path to a pip requirements file, which should be local to the remote system. File can be specified as a relative path if using the chdir option.

So if your provisioning process doesn't copy/link your local folder into vagrant box, there is no `pip-requirements.txt` available.

Comment: That worked. Could you point out to the specific doc for this?

Comment: Hmm. There's a link to module's doc in the answer, and excerpt from parameter description.